# git-cola will not run on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-cola

I have installed git-cola using the setup installer for windows. I pointed it to proper installs of git and python.

When I try to launch git-cola, nothing happens whatsoever.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case it was missing PyQt4 library. You can install PyQt4 by downloading an appropriate installer from *Binary Packages* section on [PyQt4 Riverbank website](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download).

**How I investigated the issue**

When I installed `git-cola` in a default directory and tried to run it using a command line

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\git-cola\bin>python git-cola.pyw
```

I got

```
Sorry, you do not seem to have PyQt4 installed.
Please install it before using git-cola.
e.g.: sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

**Note**

I have two Python 2.7 installations, one at `c:\program\Python27` and another at `C:\Users\UserName\Anaconda2`, I used the first one. I also installed [Python SIP](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) some time ago, I'm not sure if it required by git-cola.

Comment: Mine does not say that when I run from command line. Mine says absolutely nothing when I run from command line.

Comment: Looks like you have a different problem than I had. You can try to increasing verbosity by adding `-v` parameter i.e. `python -v git-cola.pyw`.

Comment: For anyone else reading this: my problem was that git-cola requires PySide.  At the time of this writing, PySide only supports python versions (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), and (3, 4).  Reverting from 3.6 to 2.7 did the trick.